# PySide web browser appears, but inspector doesn't display anything

Tags: python, qt, webkit, pyside

I am currently running this code, and although the web browser appears, the web inspector doesn't seem to display anything, am i doing something incorrectly?

```py
import sys
from PySide.QtCore import *
from PySide.QtGui import *
from PySide.QtWebKit import *

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

web = QWebView()
web.load(QUrl("http://www.google.com"))
web.show()

inspect = QWebInspector()
inspect.setPage(web.page())
inspect.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: From PySide Mailing List 'Hi,

You have to enable the developer extras for the QWebView.

inspect = QWebInspector()

page = web.page()
main_frame = page.mainFrame()
# Enable the Web Inspector
web_settings = view.settings()
web_settings.setAttribute(QtWebKit.QWebSettings.DeveloperExtrasEnabled, 1)

inspect.setPage(page)
inspect.show() 

Dom'

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It is in the [Qt Documentation](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qwebinspector.html):

> Note: A QWebInspector will display a
>   blank widget if either: page() is null
>   QWebSettings::DeveloperExtrasEnabled
>   is false

You must enable it, like this:

```
import sys
from PySide.QtCore import *
from PySide.QtGui import *
from PySide.QtWebKit import *

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

web = QWebView()
web.settings().setAttribute(
    QWebSettings.WebAttribute.DeveloperExtrasEnabled, True)
# or globally:
# QWebSettings.globalSettings().setAttribute(
#     QWebSettings.WebAttribute.DeveloperExtrasEnabled, True)

web.load(QUrl("http://www.google.com"))
web.show()

inspect = QWebInspector()
inspect.setPage(web.page())
inspect.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: If you find `QWebSettings.WebAttribute.DeveloperExtrasEnabled` not work, please try `QWebSettings.DeveloperExtrasEnabled`!!! (anyone explains why?)