# PySide how to get QWebInspector same window

Tags: python, qt, webkit, pyside

I just started dwelling into the realm of Qt (coming from PyGTK) and I'm using PySide. So I found this great example on [another answer here on stack exchange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5942487/pyside-webkit-basic-question).

```
import sys
from PySide.QtCore import *
from PySide.QtGui import *
from PySide.QtWebKit import *

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

web = QWebView()
web.settings().setAttribute(
  QWebSettings.WebAttribute.DeveloperExtrasEnabled, True)
# or globally:
# QWebSettings.globalSettings().setAttribute(
#     QWebSettings.WebAttribute.DeveloperExtrasEnabled, True)

web.load(QUrl("http://www.google.com"))
web.show()

inspect = QWebInspector()
inspect.setPage(web.page())
inspect.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

My question is as follows, how do I make the inspector show up in the same window instead of a new one? I understand I need to add the QWebInspector to another widget inside the main window (a vbox for example), what I want to know is how to connect that event to the signal the context menu "Inspect" triggers. In PyGTK I would need to use .connect() but I can't find the right SIGNAL for this specific action.

Thanks for your time guys/gals

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It shouldn't be necessary to do anything special for the context menu to work. Just add an inspector widget to your layout, and `hide()` it to start with. The default context menu action can then `show()` the inspector as needed.

A slightly trickier issue is how to hide the inspector again once it's shown, as there doesn't seem to be a corresponding context menu item for that.

The demo script below simply creates a keyboard shortcut to hide/show the inspector:

```
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore, QtWebKit

class Window(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.view = QtWebKit.QWebView(self)
        self.view.settings().setAttribute(
            QtWebKit.QWebSettings.WebAttribute.DeveloperExtrasEnabled, True)
        self.inspector = QtWebKit.QWebInspector(self)
        self.inspector.setPage(self.view.page())
        self.inspector.hide()
        self.splitter = QtGui.QSplitter(self)
        self.splitter.addWidget(self.view)
        self.splitter.addWidget(self.inspector)
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.splitter)
        QtGui.QShortcut(QtGui.QKeySequence('F7'), self,
            self.handleShowInspector)

    def handleShowInspector(self):
        self.inspector.setShown(self.inspector.isHidden())

if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.view.load(QtCore.QUrl('http://www.google.com'))
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: thank you, I'm still looking on how I can customize the action on the default context menu, but your answer made me understand better how the inspector object works.